# Sliding the keyboard to the left in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I'm wondering if there is a way to slide the first-responder keyboard to the left or to the right when the user press a button.

http://cl.ly/image/143K3t403d1m/1.png

I make the button as a keyboard-accessory view. When it's tapped the keyboard should slide to the left displaying another custom inputs panel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a keyboard that can be selected from the system (using the globe key), you'll need to read [this article about creating a Custom Keyboard App Extension for iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html).

If you just want to be able to switch between `inputView` objects, the following code will get you there:

```
//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () {

}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Controls
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIInputView *inputView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
@end
@implementation ViewController
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - View Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupUserInterface];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Keyboard switching
- (void)switchKeyboard {
    // Simply toggle the "inputView" for self.textField
    if (self.textField.inputView == nil) {
        self.textField.inputView    = self.inputView;
    } else {
        self.textField.inputView    = nil;
    }
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Setup 
// All of the code below here
// is for pure, in-code AutoLayout
- (void)setupUserInterface {
    [self createControls];
    [self setupControls];
    [self layoutControls];
}
- (void)createControls {
    self.textField                      = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.textField.borderStyle          = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.inputView                      = [[UIInputView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 216.0f)];
    self.inputView.backgroundColor      = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
- (void)setupControls {
    UIToolbar *toolbar                  = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44.0f)];
    toolbar.backgroundColor             = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    // When the button is tapped, it'll execute "switchKeyboard" above
    UIBarButtonItem *switchButton       = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Switch" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(switchKeyboard)];
    toolbar.items                       = @[switchButton];
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView   = toolbar;
    [self.textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

}
- (void)layoutControls {
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[textfield]-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"textfield": self.textField}]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(height)-[textfield(==height)]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:@{@"height"   : @(40)}
                                                                        views:@{@"textfield": self.textField}]];
}
@end
```

> ***Caveat:*** You will need to do a lot of tweaking to make sure the user experience is good. In my testing, on the simulator (iPhone 4S), this works ok, but isn't the smoothest user experience.

Comment: I think this works fine. But I'm not sure if I could make it animated when displaying another UIInputView?